# How to know from which direction there is a collision with an object?

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, collision, direction

In the game, there is a ball, and moving objects that can hit it.
I want the ball to move when an object hits it. But the ball should move to the right direction, the one which the collision was from.
I looked for some answers on the internet, however, most codes were in Java script, and those that were in C# weren't helpful because it needed a Rigidbody.
The ball is a rigidbody, but the objects that may hit it, aren't. Those are being moved by the CharacterController.
The question is how can I detect the collision, to know from what direction it came, and move it to that direction.
Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like something better suited for gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Collision detection is separate from the momentum calculation. Which are you having trouble with.

Comment: I guess I need both? I want to detect the collision, but also I want to know what was the vector of it, so the ball would continue moving as the current movement @JamesRalston

Answer (score 0):

I think a normalized vector from the ball to the object.

```
direction = (ball.transform.position - kicker.transform.position).normalized;
```

I made a [game](http://luigigarcia.byethost7.com/projects/goal-a-r-goal/) doing kind of this thing you are doing. (source code link in the post)